# Правильное построение БД для атрибутов товаров

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, many-to-many

Дано: атрибуты товаров (цвет, рост, производитель), которые выбираются из предложенного выбора, не свободное редактирование. Каким образом в данном случае лучше построить базу данных? Думаю вынести каждый атрибут в отдельную сущность, а потом таблицей М-М связывать конкретный товар с атрибутами, т.е. таблица `colors, products, product_has_colors`. Насколько это правильно и какие есть альтернативные варианты?

В будущем нужно будет делать фильтр для товаров по атрибутам, поэтому вариант добавлять атрибуты в json для каждого товара, думаю, не лучшая затея.

Comment: *Думаю вынести каждый атрибут в отдельную сущность* И когда появится новый атрибут - менять структуру БД??? Посмотрите, например, в направлении EAV. Да и JSON - не сказать что неприменим, всё-таки косвенно он индексируется (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-secondary-indexes.html#json-column-indirect-index).

Comment: @Akina почему же? С каждым атрибутом добавляется лишь 2 таблицы - сама сущность + связь с товаром. Должен сразу сказать, что ИМ делается только под цветы, поэтому атрибутов не может быть безграничное кол-во. По поводу EAV почитаю, спасибо!)

Comment: *С каждым атрибутом добавляется лишь 2 таблицы - сама сущность + связь с товаром.* Затвердите аки "отче наш" - клиент **НЕ ДОЛЖЕН** выполнять (и даже иметь прав на выполнение) DDL, его компетенция - исключительно данные. Исключения - редки, и это явно не Ваш случай.

Answer (score 4):

Вот я нашёл в  интернетах, кажется это подходит под вашу задачу:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/123467/schema-design-for-products-with-multiple-variants-attributes

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Обычно в БД создают таблицы-словари `DIC_COLOR`, `DIC_PRODUCER` и т.п. В основной таблице (журнале) связывают свойства по ключам словарей:
`JOR_TOVAR(NAME,ID_COLOR,ID_PRODUCER,...)`
Для внутреннего контроля можно указать связь полей по внешнему ключу (foreign key), но обычно это просто предохранитель, т.к. интерфейс все равно ограничит ввод по выборкам из таблиц-словарей. Количество и наполнение словарей - диктуется самой задачей. Но идеально, если в журналах почти все будет ID_ - ccылками (кроме дат и кол-ва). Это, если что, и будет Вам подсказкой на разделение словарей.

Answer (score 0):

1) Если все товары у вас однотипны и имеют конечное количество атрибутов, то самым лучшим выходом будет просто сделать широкую таблицу включающую в себя поля этих атрибутов.

2) Если предполагается неограниченный рост разнообразия атрибутов, то надо делать отдельный справочник атрибутов и заводить таблицу связываний продуктов с атрибутами

```
CREATE TABLE products{
    id INT
    ...
}

CREATE TABLE attributes{
    id INT,
    name VARCHAR,
    ....
}

CREATE TABLE productAttributes{
    productId INT,    <- внешний ключ для products.id
    attrId INT,       <- внешний ключ для attributes.id
    value VARCHAR
}
```

Такой способ крайне универсален, но более сложен в части работы с данными.